# Best Practice Windows Store App WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, windows-8

What is the best way of using a WCF serivce reference in a Windows Store App?

I've been spending quite some time making ObservableCollections with ObservableProperties which bind with CompositeTypes in my WCF service, however it has turned into a pain in the neck, and has restricted me quite a bit in the navigation between pages in my app.

Maybe I went too fast and should have read a standard method people use which I am not aware of. I feel like I need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: Are you developing WCF service or consuming it ?

Comment: I'm developing and consuming it.

Comment: Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233.aspx),    [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/09/22/wcf-in-win8-metro-styled-apps-absolutely-supported.aspx) & [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nishasingh/archive/2012/12/05/creating-and-deploying-a-wcf-service-on-windows-azure-and-consuming-it-in-windows-8-store-app.aspx)  and let me know if you face any problems

Comment: Hey thanks for the links! I think the MVVM pattern is what I'm looking for. I'm going to dig further.